# How to scan a QR Code in WinUI 3 using webcam?

Tags: c#, qr-code, webcam, zxing, winui-3

I'm trying to scan a QR-Code from WebCam in WinUI 3. I've installed ZXing and AForge Video but these libraries doesn't work properly in WinUI 3. Are there any solutions or more compatible alternatives?

Comment: This [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4710) might help.

Comment: Also see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1324731/help-with-camera-preview about the usage of camera exploration in WinUI3. You can suggest features on [WindowsAPPSDK productboard portal](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK#contributing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZXing ([ZXing.NET](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net) is a port) is completely platform agnostic, so it works fine with any technology as long as you can capture a "bitmap" (RGB, etc.) of some kind whatever that means on a given platform.

Here is WinUI3 (make sure you have the latest WinUI3 nugets installed) sample application that does two things:

- It captures the (first on your PC) webcam outputs and displays it in a WinUI3 [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/media-playback).
- For each frame, it runs ZXing barcode reader decoding, trying to find a QR Code, and it displays it when it finds one.

The code could be easily changed to read any barcode (EAN13, etc.) that XZing supports. It contains a thin adaptation layer between XZing and WinRT's SoftwareBitmap (that I have copied from XZing.NET code):

Here is the XAML for a WinUI3 page:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Click="Button_Click">Toggle Capture</Button>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Grid.Row="1" />
    <MediaPlayerElement
        x:Name="player"
        Grid.Row="2"
        Width="600"
        Height="600"
        AutoPlay="True" />
</Grid>
```

And the code in a WinUI3 page (you need the XZing.NET nuget package installed):

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly SoftwareBitmapBarcodeReader _reader;
    private MediaCapture _capture;
    private MediaFrameReader _frameReader;
    private MediaSource _mediaSource;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // set various xzing options (beware, all formats like All_1D can divide perf by orders of magnitude)
        _reader = new SoftwareBitmapBarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true
        };
        _reader.Options.PossibleFormats = new[] { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE };
        _reader.Options.TryHarder = true;
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_capture == null)
        {
            await InitializeCaptureAsync();
            return;
        }
        await TerminateCaptureAsync();
    }

    private async Task InitializeCaptureAsync()
    {
        // get first capture device (change this if you want)
        var sourceGroup = (await MediaFrameSourceGroup.FindAllAsync())?.FirstOrDefault();
        if (sourceGroup == null)
            return; // not found!

        // init capture & initialize
        _capture = new MediaCapture();
        await _capture.InitializeAsync(new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings
        {
            SourceGroup = sourceGroup,
            SharingMode = MediaCaptureSharingMode.SharedReadOnly,
            MemoryPreference = MediaCaptureMemoryPreference.Cpu, // to ensure we get SoftwareBitmaps
        });

        // initialize source
        var source = _capture.FrameSources[sourceGroup.SourceInfos[0].Id];

        // create reader to get frames & pass reader to player to visualize the webcam
        _frameReader = await _capture.CreateFrameReaderAsync(source, MediaEncodingSubtypes.Bgra8);
        _frameReader.FrameArrived += OnFrameArrived;
        await _frameReader.StartAsync();

        _mediaSource = MediaSource.CreateFromMediaFrameSource(source);
        player.Source = _mediaSource;
    }

    private void OnFrameArrived(MediaFrameReader sender, MediaFrameArrivedEventArgs args)
    {
        var bmp = sender.TryAcquireLatestFrame()?.VideoMediaFrame?.SoftwareBitmap;
        if (bmp == null)
            return;

        var result = _reader.Decode(bmp);
        if (result != null)
        {
            // found a QR CODE
            DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
            {
                textBox.Text = result.BarcodeFormat + ": " + result.Text;
            });
        }
    }

    private async Task TerminateCaptureAsync()
    {
        player.Source = null;

        _mediaSource?.Dispose();
        _mediaSource = null;

        if (_frameReader != null)
        {
            _frameReader.FrameArrived -= OnFrameArrived;
            await _frameReader.StopAsync();
            _frameReader?.Dispose();
            _frameReader = null;
        }

        _capture?.Dispose();
        _capture = null;
    }
}

// this is the thin layer that allows you to use XZing over WinRT's SoftwareBitmap
public class SoftwareBitmapBarcodeReader : BarcodeReader<SoftwareBitmap>
{
    public SoftwareBitmapBarcodeReader()
        : base(bmp => new SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource(bmp))
    {
    }
}

// from https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/blob/master/Source/lib/BitmapLuminanceSource.SoftwareBitmap.cs
public class SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource : BaseLuminanceSource
{
    protected SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource(int width, int height)
      : base(width, height)
    {
    }

    public SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource(SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap)
        : base(softwareBitmap.PixelWidth, softwareBitmap.PixelHeight)
    {
        if (softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat != BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8)
        {
            using SoftwareBitmap convertedSoftwareBitmap = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(softwareBitmap, BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8);
            convertedSoftwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(luminances.AsBuffer());
            return;
        }
        softwareBitmap.CopyToBuffer(luminances.AsBuffer());
    }

    protected override LuminanceSource CreateLuminanceSource(byte[] newLuminances, int width, int height)
        => new SoftwareBitmapLuminanceSource(width, height) { luminances = newLuminances };
}
```

And here is the result on a QR Code that encodes "Hello World":

[image]

Comment: I've tried your solution and I can see the camera preview. But every time the app have scanned a qr-code, it throws an exception at `var result = _reader.Decode(bmp);`. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDZ4j.png)

Comment: That's a ZXing issue. Makre sure you have the latest nuget. May be a multithreading issue, try to put a C# lock around _reader decode. Or catch and continue. Or report to the ZXing.net site.

Comment: I noticed that the `TerminateCaptureAsync()` method doesn't terminate the camera capture properly. After calling the method and even after closing the window (just the window not the application) the camera is still running.

Comment: @Finn - I don't have that problem, but this is sample code, you may have to adapt things