# Asynchronous IMFSourceReader::ReadSample sporadically returns MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation

I'm trying to write a class that would read video input from a webcam. I'm using Media Foundation for that. The full code is similar to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/medfound/using-the-source-reader-in-asynchronous-mode). In a nutshell I'm using [`IMFSourceReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nn-mfreadwrite-imfsourcereader) to initiate an asynchronous read.

My particular code does:

```
HRESULT hr = srcReader->SetStreamSelection(streamIdx, TRUE);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

hr = srcReader->ReadSample(streamIdx,
                        0,
                        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
```

It works most of the time, except sometimes `IMFSourceReader::ReadSample` or `IMFSourceReader::SetStreamSelection` return `MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST` or `0xc00d36b2` and my `assert` fails:

> The request is invalid in the current state.

Btw, the reason I started using `IMFSourceReader::SetStreamSelection` is because I read somewhere that I need to select a stream to prevent that error message.

Any idea what that error message means and how to deal with it?

Comment: FWIW, it's much easier with WinRT (which wraps MF under the surface), there's a sample here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76964419/403671 in C# but it's quite the same code with C++. The interesting part is in InitializeCaptureAsync. You can plug the output on existing sinks or get frames one by one.

Comment: @SimonMourier you know if I retry the same API after `MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST` (with a `Sleep(1)` delay), it seems to work. I have no idea why though.

Comment: @SimonMourier On an unrelated note. (I see that you know this stuff quite well.) Off the top of your head, do you know if `IMFSourceReader` supports flipping the image from a webcam? Horizontally or vertically.

Comment: I can't fully answer but I don't think this type of operation would be available at stream level.

Comment: @SimonMourier that's what I thought too. Thanks.

Comment: IMO the question does not have sufficient detail, my guess would be that you don't have good order of calls. If you requests a frame asynchronouly, you can't do it again before you actually receive asynchronouly the frame you already requested earlier. If your second call is too early, you hit this wrong state thing. I personally never ever had this error with a lot of async usage.

Comment: @RomanR. the next frame is indeed requested only if a previous one is processed. As for you not seeing it before, to test my app, I have 3 different webcams. And only one gives me this error and not right away. I have to leave the app running for 10-20 min before I can see it in a debugger. The odd thing is that after I repeat the same call (to the same function that returned MF_E_INVALIDREQUEST) it usually goes through. My guess is that it is returned because of some internal communication discrepancy between the user-layer API and the driver. But it's just a guess.